# Configurable product import issue

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I had imported configurable product then after when open the configurable product every time it display :Only attributes with scope "Global", input type "Dropdown" and Use To Create Configurable Product "Yes" are available" message.It should be not appear this window while open the configure product.

[image]

[image]